# Can't find Guava 20.0-SNAPSHOT artifact

Tags: java, git, maven, github, guava

I have a project hosted on GitHub, with a branch I'm using for developing a new version: https://github.com/jrtom/jung/tree/common.graph

The master branch (v2.1.1) builds fine.

The `common.graph` branch differs from `master` in only two ways:

1. I've bumped the version in the `pom.xml` files from `2.2-SNAPSHOT` to `3.0-SNAPSHOT`.  This is effectively cosmetic.
2. I've bumped the Guava dependency version from `19.0` to `20.0-SNAPSHOT`, so that I can start developing against the new features.
   This is the correct dependency per the Guava documentation: https://github.com/google/guava#snapshots

A pull request of the `common.graph` branch successfully builds via Travis: https://github.com/jrtom/jung/pull/65

However, when I clone this branch:

```
git clone --branch common.graph --single-branch git@github.com:jrtom/jung.git jung_3.0
```

and then run `mvn install`, I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project jung-api: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project net.sf.jung:jung-api:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT:
Could not find artifact com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Blowing away the local repository under ~/.m2/repository has no effect.

As far as I can tell--from reading Maven documentation, from looking at other `pom.xml` files that reference Guava's snapshot of v20--this change should Just Work, but it doesn't.

Changing the Guava dependency to `18.0` **does** work.  So it seems like something wacky with the `-SNAPSHOT` specification, but I don't see how.

Any advice/pointers would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

@RC.'s response below pointed me in the correct direction, although I still needed to figure out the right repository spec for Google snapshots.  For future reference, here's the spec:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>google-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Always look on Maven central to see if your artifact is available. [Guava 20.0.0-SNAPSHOT is not](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.guava%22%20AND%20a%3A%22guava%22).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snapshots are not pushed in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.guava%22%20AND%20a%3A%22guava%22) for obvious reasons.

If you really want guava snapshots, it [seems](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2259) they are pushed in this [repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/guava/guava/20.0-SNAPSHOT/)

To [add a custom repository](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) to your pom, use something like (adapted from the doc):

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <id>sonatype-OSS-snaphots</id>
      <name>Sonatype OSS Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Comment: RC: thanks for the information; I'm not a Maven expert so it's not immediately obvious to me why snapshots wouldn't be pushed to Maven's central repo.  Anyway, I'm updating my original question to show the correct spec for the Google snapshot repository, now that I've figured out the details.

Comment: Glad your issue is now fixed :) One of the reason they're not in central is there are a lot of them, for guava there is many snapshots per day, imagine that for N projects (maven central is huge, see http://search.maven.org/#stats) Another reason is that snapshot can be unstable, very unstable sometimes.